# Jetty - duplicates the already loaded file

Tags: web-applications, maven, plugins, jetty

So I have been trying to configure jetty maven plugin to run an application. So here is the premesis:

My application depends on a WAR, basically I pull that WAR overlay some libraries this is using maven overlay feature. Now application builds fine with maven for tomcat/jboss but here is the twist. Jetty builds the application, then fetches that war again into some temp directory and starts loading same thing all over again where I get an exception:

ava.lang.RuntimeException: Message properties file URL [jar:file:/C:/my_m2_repo/some.war!/WEB-INF/classes/messages/messages.properties] duplicates the already loaded file [C:\src\myApp\applications\market\target\tmp\webinf\WEB-INF\classes\messages\messages.properties] - and this is that "tmp" folder jetty plugin creates additionally where it unpacks that WAR it fetched from local repo without any overlays etc...

Please advise.

using jetty-7.1.6.v20100715

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <jettyEnvXml>jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                </webAppConfig>

                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9090</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>


                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I am not going to pass down jetty-env.xml as it's some JNDI argments they seem to be legit.

Comment: Did you try to run Maven clean command before the jetty:run one?

Comment: yes, but I got a workaround by jetty:run-war